# How to get each value from specific key from a JSON in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, key-value

I have the following JSON:

```
{"connection": {
"informations": {},
"id_user": 6909,
"subscriptions": [
    {
        "id_source": 69825,
        "documents": [
            {
                "id_subscription": 5265,
                "thumb_url": "https://test-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1244/thumbnail/test%40hotmail.fr_305146953_thumbnail.png",
                "name": "Facture de 44.96€ du 2019-11-18",
                "id_thumbnail": 40343,
                "url": "https://test-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1244/file/test%40hotmail.fr_305146953.pdf",
                "untaxed_amount": null
            },
            {
                "id_subscription": 5265,
                "thumb_url": "https://mooncard23-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1245/thumbnail/test%40hotmail.fr_290804394_thumbnail.png",
                "name": "Facture de 13.98€ du 2019-05-29",
                "url": "https://mooncard23-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1245/file/test%40hotmail.fr_290804394.pdf",
                "untaxed_amount": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
}
```

I try to get all the values like "`https://test-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1246/file/test%40hotmail.fr_274475652.pdf`"

My JSON is rendered like this in my controller:

```
render json: params.to_json
```

When I try to get all the values URL in this way:

```
params.dig('connection','subscriptions').each_with_object([]) { |x, arr| x['documents'].each { |d| arr << d['url'] } }
```

I have the error `undefined method each_with_object for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". When you fail to reduce the code or data to the minimum necessary you waste your own time, and ours, because you make it harder for us to help you by throwing unnecessary information at us. It's your job to minimize the noise so we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: Edit the question, reduce the code and data and explain what "it's not working" means: Do you get an error, do you get nothing, do you get the wrong result? Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple as simple solution that is easy to understand.
You can try this:

```
JSON.parse(params)["invoice"]["connection"]["subscriptions"].map { |subscription|
  subscription["documents"].map{ |document| document["url"] }
}
```

```
[[
 "https://mooncard23-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1244/file/test%40hotmail.fr_305146953.pdf",
 "https://mooncard23-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1245/file/test%40hotmail.fr_290804394.pdf",
 "https://mooncard23-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/users/me/documents/1246/file/test%40hotmail.fr_274475652.pdf"
]]
```

Comment: If params is JSON then add params.to_json in above code snippet.
```JSON.parse(params.to_json)["invoice"]["connection"]["subscriptions"].map{|subscription| subscription["documents"].map{|document| document["url"]}}```

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding additional info in the comment section

Comment: Please read "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" and
"[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)", then edit your answer and correct the formatting. SO is like a reference book where formatting is important to help others understand what you're trying to pass on.

Comment: @Viktor, please don't edit people's code in questions or answers. Formatting and correcting indent are acceptable but the content of the code is for the person posting to fix. It's OK to suggest changes in a comment but it's up to them to correct or implement the changes.

Comment: @theTinMan Okay

Comment: Do not replace `{` or `}` with `do` and `end`. We do not correct people's code in their posting. By changing it you change their intent. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266467/128421.

Comment: @theTinMan I read the rules after asking, sorry about the confusion. I hope adding newlines is ok to make it more readable ?